# Blocked from sharing posts on Facebook, told to slow down

Tags: facebook, sharing

I am having trouble with sharing posts with friends or posting on my timeline. After about five or six 'shares', I get the message:

> slow down, you are going too fast or your are using this feature for which it was not intended?

I don't understand this because I don't go fast when posting. I have never been accused of going too fast.

There must be a bug in the system because after an hour or so, I am able to re-post after it tells me that I am blocked from sharing posts for two days. The next day I try to post again, and it allows me to share.

Why does it give me this message if I am not truly blocked for two days?

This doesn't make any sense. I have never had this happen to me before. I am not using/sharing posts in a way that was not intended.

If posts are sent out with permission to 'share' then why do I receive this strange message?

I am not able to use Facebook as before, and there are some very lovely posts that I would like to share with friends or just put on my timeline.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Facebook? They could have flagged you in some way that makes you more prone to spam detection.

Comment: What is the rate of your posts really? I mean how many posts do you do per day when you are not blocked?

Answer (score 0):

That has happened to me at arbitrary times for arbitrary amounts of editing.

Fact is there is not any specification or documentation of what that involves. due to the common line lately that that is all proprietary policy/legal logic.

(The fact that you are nervous and confused now is likely due to you not receiving any status notification of the speed ticket, normally for car speeding tickets you at least get a receipt with a radar reading and a timestamp if not also the officer's badge number.)

Comment: I will comment that I always edited like that since homework and grade school and did not find a speeding ticket, actually got rewarded.

Comment: Editing today that got the error again, was after editing a single "Facebook Note", a few years ago I had the same exact error for making multiple "Facebook Statuses", however the editing of a single document raising that alert for text processing is nervewracking.

Comment: I was taught writing requires editing.so that alert is another education entirely (what is the verbal equivalence, moderation through verbal abuse tactics?), if even called education, and while notably often called moderation, that resembes a speeding ticket given by uniformed police employed as law enforcement, so what clear and objective determination are we making for public policy and law? We're legislating the text processing of a single document now, with reactions akin to actual computer bugs, as a social protocol?