# Like-button and problems

Tags: facebook-like

When I go to Facebook there are sometimes 200-300 hundred pics and stories that I try to read.  There are lots of pics that I like.  When i have liked about 100 pics, and read the text that goes with them, Facebook says "you are using this operation too fast, you have to do it slower or you may be prevented from using this feature".

I don´t like it all. I have about 50 friends plus friends of friends. I can't use Facebook without that phrase popping up in after every like after that!

Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: Related: [Blocked from sharing posts on Facebook, told to slow down](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37946)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. These are measures taken server-side by Facebook to prevent spamming, viruses etc.